# Generating Java Code from WSDL

Tags: web-services, soap, apache-axis, axis, rpc

I have to generate Java code from a wsdl file. Currently my project uses wsimport, but the wsdl file for which I have to generate code has RPC encoding. wsimport has no support for RPC. I tried using axis but it fails with following error:

**soap:fault element not recognized for soap 1.2 binding**

I found a jira already for this issue:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2614

axis2 doesn't support RPC. Is there any other way I can generate the code from the wsdl using maven.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using JAX-RPC instead of axis

http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/tutorial/doc/IntroWS5.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. Have a look at this article: [How do I write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Axis1 framework. It is old, but available on https://axis.apache.org/axis There you can find a tool called wsdl2Java, which you can execute like:

```
java -cp <all jars of the framework> \
org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java \
-p <destination package name> \
-o <destination src path> \
http://[Servername]/MyService?wsdl
```

This generates all classes from the wsdl service description file. Then you can use the Stub classes to access the service.

The last snapshot version you can find on https://builds.apache.org/job/axis-trunk 
Click on "Last Build" and then on "Distribution" (or Maven Plugin).